# cant get canvas image to show

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Need help. Can't get image to show in dreamweaver. I've tried with an image that's on my computer as well, still doesn't show. Newbie to both HTML and JS

http://jsfiddle.net/Alquh/gpceqb8t/

```
<canvas id="test" width="650" height="600"></canvas>
window.onload = function () {
var context1 = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d");


var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    context1.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 25);
};
imageObj.src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300";
```

};

```
 <style type="text/css"> canvas {
 border: 1px solid black;
```

}

Comment: Your fiddle is not setup correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/gpceqb8t/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are missing some HTML or JavaScript core fragments then you put everything together.

Here is the whole HTML file code, that works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        } 
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <canvas id="test" width="650" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
        var context1 = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d");

        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function () {
            context1.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 25);
        };
        imageObj.src = "http://placekitten.com/g/600/650/";

    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Your link for imageObj.src is wrong in your code (http://placekitten.com/200/300 - it does not show any picture)